# How to fix the error: 'This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it'

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto3, digital-ocean, django-storage

I hosted a small django project on virtual machine on digital ocean. Before I started using digital ocean to serve static files everything worked fine. But immediately I created a storage space and push my static files there the static files are not being served on the webpage, including django admin page (the project pages are showing `net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)`. I have already installed django_storages and boto3.
I got some hint as to the possible cause of the problem when I clicked on digital ocean aws bucket url that looks like `https://django-space-storage.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com`. When I cliked on it I got the following error:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
```

It seems the browser is rendering my django pages as xml instead of html. I might be wrong with this assumption because I'm finding a hard time trying to understand what is actually going on. My question is, how do I cause the browser to render my django pages as html instead of xml?